# How to write pipe in text in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Helloworld this is a very long sentence Helloworld this is a very long sentence Helloworld this is a very long sentence Helloworld this is a very long sentence Helloworld this is a very long sentence `|Liver|CNS|Lungs`. 
\end{document}
```

I have this in my body `|Liver|CNS|Lungs` which goes over the margin:

[image]

How can you type pipes in your body?

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)